# jQuery equivalent of curl command

Tags: jquery, json, curl

The site in question is http://echojson.com/

Using curl you can do:

```
curl --globoff -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X DELETE http://echojson.com/_history
```

To clear the history.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://echojson.com/_history',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
  });
```

gives me

```
OPTIONS http://echojson.com/_history [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 110ms]
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [jQuery Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),

> Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be
>   used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

I tested it with [Firefox on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/AYaKoVi/1/) and got in Fiddler the same result: My request header is

```
OPTIONS /_history HTTP/1.1
```

I don't know, if it works in Chrome or other browsers, but it seems, that your only possibility is, if you really need DELETE requests, send GET requests to your server and let the server execute the DELETE request.